# How to check whether the value in mysql filed is inserted or not?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to check whether the field value of mysql is inserted or not?

I am developing a job portal in that the logged in users first upload the resume then only apply for the job, if they try to apply for the job it checks whether resume is uploaded or not , if not uploaded take that to upload resume page after upload again redirect to apply job page,if resume uploaded apply for the job easily, how can i do that one

Comment: bro simple if ($insert){  echo "insert success";} else { echo "insert not success";}

Answer (score 0):

[See here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error.
>
> For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc, mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error.